# How does pages work if the DB is manipulated between next

Tags: spring-data

The below code i have is working as intended, but is there a better way to do it?

I am consuming a db like a queue and process in batches of a max number. I'm thinking on how i can refactor it to use `page.hasNext()` and `page.nextPageable()`

However I can't find any good tutorial/documentation on what happens if the DB is manipulated between getting a page and getting the next page.

```
List<Customer> toBeProcessedList = customerToBeProcessedRepo
            .findFirstXAsCustomer(new PageRequest(0, MAX_NR_TO_PROCESS));
while (!toBeProcessedList.isEmpty()) {
    //do something with each customer and
    //remove customer, and it's duplicates from the customersToBeProcessed
    toBeProcessedList = customerToBeProcessedRepo
                .findFirstXAsCustomer(new PageRequest(0, MAX_NR_TO_PROCESS));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the paging support for each page requested a new sql statement gets executed, and if you don't do something fancy (and probably stupid) they get executed in different transactions. This can lead to getting elements multiple times or not seeing them at all, when the user moves from page to page.

Example: Page size 3; Elements to start: A, B, C, D, E, F

User opens the first page and sees

A, B, C (total number of pages is 2)

element X gets inserted after B; User moves to the next page and sees

C, D, E (total number of pages is now 3)

if instead of adding X, C gets deleted, the page 2 will show

E, F

since D moves to the first page.

In theory one could have a long running transaction with read stability (if supported by the underlying database) so one gets consistent pages, BUT this opens up questions like:

- When does this transaction end, so the user gets to see new/changed data
- When does this transaction end, when the user moves away?
- This approach would have some rather high resource costs, while the actual benefit is not at all clear

So in 99 of 100 cases the default approach is pretty reasonable.

Footnote: I kind of assumed relational databases, but other stores should behave in basically the same way.

Comment: So if you read page 1 you get ABC, and if you then remove C, when reading page 2 you get CDE, or only E (as d has been "moved" to page 1)?

Comment: @ViktorMellgren added a variant of the example to answer that.

Comment: thanks, that was how i expected it to work, but didn't find any good examples. Thank you!